# Netbeans platform application hang in java7u40 AppKit thread

Tags: java, macos, swing, java-7, netbeans-platform

This is thread dump while the apllication is not hanging:
http://pastebin.com/NdJu4yUB

And this is one while hanging:

```
Full thread dump

"Timer-2,Thomass-MacBook-Pro-40578@21" daemon prio=5 tid=0x3a nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2176)
      at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery$Responses.get(Katalis.java:723)
      at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.findMembers(Katalis.java:238)
      at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.findAllViews(Katalis.java:211)
      at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.down(Katalis.java:547)
      at org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE2$FindSubgroupsTask.findAllViews(Katalis.java:348)
      at org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE2$FindSubgroupsTask._findAndNotify(Katalis.java:283)
      at org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE2$FindSubgroupsTask.findAndNotify(Katalis.java:271)
      at org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE2$FindSubgroupsTask$1.run(Katalis.java:244)
      at org.jgroups.util.TimeScheduler3$Task.run(Katalis.java:279)
      at org.jgroups.util.TimeScheduler3$RecurringTask.run(Katalis.java:310)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"AWT-EventQueue-0@38" prio=6 tid=0x16 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
      at java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent(EventQueue.java:543)
      at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
      at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
      at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
      at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
      at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
      at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

"pool-1-thread-1@33" prio=5 tid=0x26 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1079)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"Hibernate Search: Directory writer-1@2" prio=5 tid=0x50 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"Hibernate Search: Directory writer-1@3" prio=5 tid=0x4f nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"SwingWorker-pool-8-thread-10@7" daemon prio=5 tid=0x49 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"SwingWorker-pool-8-thread-9@8" daemon prio=5 tid=0x48 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"SwingWorker-pool-8-thread-8@9" daemon prio=5 tid=0x47 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"SwingWorker-pool-8-thread-7@10" daemon prio=5 tid=0x46 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"SwingWorker-pool-8-thread-6@11" daemon prio=5 tid=0x45 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"SwingWorker-pool-8-thread-5@12" daemon prio=5 tid=0x44 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"SwingWorker-pool-8-thread-4@13" daemon prio=5 tid=0x43 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"OOB-3,Thomass-MacBook-Pro-40578@15" prio=5 tid=0x40 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"OOB-2,Thomass-MacBook-Pro-40578@16" prio=5 tid=0x3f nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"OOB-1,Thomass-MacBook-Pro-40578@17" prio=5 tid=0x3e nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"SwingWorker-pool-8-thread-3@28" daemon prio=5 tid=0x31 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"SwingWorker-pool-8-thread-2@30" daemon prio=5 tid=0x2a nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"SwingWorker-pool-8-thread-1@31" daemon prio=5 tid=0x28 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"pool-4-thread-1@35" prio=5 tid=0x1c nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"multicast receiver,Thomass-MacBook-Pro-40578@19" prio=5 tid=0x3c nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.peekData(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:-1)
      - locked <0x46> (a java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl)
      at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:726)
      - locked <0x47> (a java.net.MulticastSocket)
      - locked <0x48> (a java.net.DatagramPacket)
      at org.jgroups.protocols.UDP$PacketReceiver.run(Katalis.java:674)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"Timer runner-1,Thomass-MacBook-Pro-40578@23" daemon prio=5 tid=0x37 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
      at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(DelayQueue.java:220)
      at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(DelayQueue.java:68)
      at org.jgroups.util.TimeScheduler3.run(Katalis.java:164)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"TimerQueue@36" daemon prio=5 tid=0x1a nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
      at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(DelayQueue.java:209)
      at javax.swing.TimerQueue.run(TimerQueue.java:171)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"AppKit Thread@43" daemon prio=5 tid=0xf nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit.doAWTRunLoop(LWCToolkit.java:-1)
      at sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit.invokeAndWait(LWCToolkit.java:549)
      at sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit.invokeAndWait(LWCToolkit.java:489)
      at sun.lwawt.macosx.CAccessibility.invokeAndWait(CAccessibility.java:75)
      at sun.lwawt.macosx.CAccessibility.getFocusOwner(CAccessibility.java:521)

"Active Reference Queue Daemon@41" daemon prio=1 tid=0x13 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
      at org.openide.util.lookup.implspi.ActiveQueue$Impl.run(ActiveQueue.java:59)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"Thread-21@6" daemon prio=5 tid=0x4a nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
      at java.util.prefs.AbstractPreferences$EventDispatchThread.run(AbstractPreferences.java:1476)

"Abandoned connection cleanup thread@29" daemon prio=5 tid=0x2b nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(Katalis.java:40)

"Inactive RequestProcessor thread [Was:Logging Flush/org.netbeans.core.startup.TopLogging$NonClose]@4" daemon prio=1 tid=0x4e nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:1910)

"C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hgfeqy8xj2ajkv1yfkb3b|7954116a]-HelperThread-#2@24" daemon prio=5 tid=0x35 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$c.run(Katalis.java:635)

"C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hgfeqy8xj2ajkv1yfkb3b|7954116a]-HelperThread-#1@25" daemon prio=5 tid=0x34 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$c.run(Katalis.java:635)

"C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hgfeqy8xj2ajkv1yfkb3b|7954116a]-HelperThread-#0@26" daemon prio=5 tid=0x33 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$c.run(Katalis.java:635)

"Java2D Queue Flusher@40" daemon prio=10 tid=0x14 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLRenderQueue$QueueFlusher.run(OGLRenderQueue.java:208)

"FD_SOCK acceptor,Thomass-MacBook-Pro-40578@18" daemon prio=5 tid=0x3d nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(PlainSocketImpl.java:-1)
      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
      at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:530)
      at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:498)
      at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK$c.run(Katalis.java:1039)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"unicast receiver,Thomass-MacBook-Pro-40578@20" prio=5 tid=0x3b nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:-1)
      - locked <0x4e> (a java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl)
      at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:145)
      at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:786)
      - locked <0x4f> (a java.net.DatagramSocket)
      - locked <0x50> (a java.net.DatagramPacket)
      at org.jgroups.protocols.UDP$PacketReceiver.run(Katalis.java:674)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"CLI Requests Server@44" daemon prio=5 tid=0xe nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(PlainSocketImpl.java:-1)
      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
      at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:530)
      at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:498)
      at org.netbeans.CLIHandler$Server.run(CLIHandler.java:1037)

"net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@25e9c476@14" daemon prio=5 tid=0x41 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
      at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
      at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"EH_CACHE Async Replication Thread@22" daemon prio=5 tid=0x39 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
      at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
      at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hgfeqy8xj2ajkv1yfkb3b|7954116a]-AdminTaskTimer@27" daemon prio=5 tid=0x32 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
      at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"SpringSingleton@32" daemon prio=5 tid=0x27 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
      at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"Timer-2@34" daemon prio=5 tid=0x24 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
      at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
      at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"Timer-1@37" prio=5 tid=0x17 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
      at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"Java2D Disposer@39" daemon prio=10 tid=0x15 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
      at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Disposer.java:145)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"AWT-Shutdown@42" prio=5 tid=0x10 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
      at sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown.run(AWTAutoShutdown.java:287)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"Timer-0@45" daemon prio=5 tid=0xb nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
      at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"Finalizer@47" daemon prio=8 tid=0x3 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
      at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:189)

"Reference Handler@48" daemon prio=10 tid=0x2 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
      at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)

"DestroyJavaVM@5" prio=5 tid=0x4c nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher@46" daemon prio=9 tid=0x4 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
```

I think that this thread is the suspect:

```
"AppKit Thread@43" daemon prio=5 tid=0xf nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit.doAWTRunLoop(LWCToolkit.java:-1)
      at sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit.invokeAndWait(LWCToolkit.java:549)
      at sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit.invokeAndWait(LWCToolkit.java:489)
      at sun.lwawt.macosx.CAccessibility.invokeAndWait(CAccessibility.java:75)
      at sun.lwawt.macosx.CAccessibility.getFocusOwner(CAccessibility.java:521)
```

I have evaluated my use of locks and not found any possible deadlock/race condition. I read in https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/MacOSXPort/Java+vs.+AppKit+Threading+Manifesto that AppKit is very easy to deadlock.

I use java7u40 on osx 10.8.5. I notice that this does not happen on my client computer with osx 10.8.x and java7u25.

My question is how to troubleshoot the cause. Thank you.

Comment: yes there are a few threads about interesting bugs (in last two-three days) by using JRE7_40, we are internal command to remove/un_install all JREs manually or waiting for stable JRE

Comment: Is there any link/url about the threads?

Comment: not this is rules in our company, there isn't public link